# Is the following mission profile appropriate for a manned mission?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, technology, space-travel, space-colonization

My idea was to use 2 stages for an interstellar spacecraft (particularly the [Orion Drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Orion_(nuclear_propulsion))) and use it in a way similar to [Project: Daedalus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Daedalus). Phase 1 would involve accelerating to cruising speed following assembly in orbit, and that cruising speed is 0.04 c, which will then slow down as we approach the [Wolf 1061c (the target planet)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolf_1061c) system in Phase 2. The First Stage is the Earth/Sol Departure Stage and then we have the second stage decelerate in the target system, known as the System Insertion Stage and enter the orbit of the planet. The two will accelerate/decelerate at 1 G/9.81 m/s^2, for 14 days to reach the 0.04 c mark, send a seedship-sleeper ship hybrid and spend the rest of the trip cruising. There is a problem; is this appropriate? If not, what are some issues I need to concern myself with?

EDIT #1: I am also going to provide a link for those of you who do not know what "mission profile" is by giving you a hands-on interplanetary or orbital example. [Mission Profile Description, Definition and Example](http://science.ksc.nasa.gov/shuttle/technology/sts-newsref/mission_profile.html#mission_profile)

EDIT #2: And the technology in this setting is very near-term, for the purposes of making a spacecraft with plausible technology. In addition, the purpose is to basically colonise a new planet. However, by the time they arrive.....well, you boys and girls might wish to kiss humanity on Earth goodbye. :P

Comment: Seem fine to me

Comment: @BryanMcClure Even with near-term technology?

Comment: This is very similar to [what you asked over here](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/39646/760) so [my answer is going to be the same](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/39655/760) (tl;dr: it's too slow and deceleration will be very, very, very expensive). I'd suggest instead of asking "will this solution work" to ask "here's the situation and the goals, how can I make this work". Like, "the  Earth will be uninhabitable in 20 years, we think Wolf 1016c is habitable, how can we send an ark?"

Comment: @Schwern Good idea. :/

Comment: What would you do for mid-course correction and flight profile adjustments? How would you manage heat during deceleration?

Comment: Well, Schwern already pointed out it's too slow. I guess it would be better to ask: Why do you want it to be so slow? That slow, you'd have to build it as a generation ship, and the mission would be completed by the children or grandchildren of the original crew members. That is assuming they don't have suspended animation tech, as your stipulation of very near-term tech suggests.

There's no practical way to carry enough food for a voyage of that length, so the ship will have to be built as an O'Neill space colony, raising food inside and recycling everything.

Comment: (Continuing...) So your choices are: 1. Speed things up with a faster space drive, // 2. Assume suspended animation, so the crew spends most of their time in cold sleep in which they need no food, or // 3. Assume a "generation ship" with the ship built as a self-contained ecosystem, raising food crops en route and not relying on stored food. /// 

In any case, the most practical approach is to have the "colonists", their crops, & their domesticated animals, all carried as frozen embryos, with just a few crew members to act as caretakers, babysitters to raise the first generation of colonists.

Comment: @Lensman That was the idea from the very start, actually. :)

Comment: use Variable Specific Impulse Magnetoplasma Rocket (VASIMR) is an electromagnetic thruster for spacecraft propulsion.

Comment: hard-science, science-based, or reality-check? I think I mentioned this in response to another question of yours, but you have to pick one. hard-science is the most strict, and basically implies that any answer given here should be equally valid had the question been asked on, say, [space.se]. You may also want to add the **spaceflight** tag, which you will be able to do once you remove the two superfluous ones.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling This was at least a month earlier. So....back then I was unaware. :P

Comment: I think this would work better as reality-check rather than hard-science. It's more likely to get an answer that way and the question feels like you are asking "is X possible/realistic".

Comment: How is this question different from http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/39646/is-this-an-appropriate-manned-interstellar-mission-profile - why is it not a duplicate?

Answer (score 3):

It's probably plausible in terms of the *physics*. Following the Project Daedalus mission plan ensures that. But the economics are a different problem.

We haven't developed laser inertial confinement fusion to a working level yet. That will be expensive. Project Daedalus reckoned mining of gas giant atmospheres was necessary to get the fuel, which means having a lot of complicated industrial infrastructure in places where we can currently send probes weighing a few tons. We're missing the AI tech for the probe to be self-maintaining and self-repairing over decades: our approach with probes is to have very few moving parts, which isn't really viable for this mission.

And then there's the scale problem. The Daedalus probe weighed 54,000 tons, including 500 tons of payload. Let's be generous and assume we can do the colony job with 5,000 tons of payload. Our vessel is now 540,000 tons. And that's got enough delta-V to slow down from cruise, but to boost it to cruise, we need the departure stage. And our cruise stage with fuel is the payload for that. At a mass-ratio of about 1:100. So the complete ship is about 50,000,000 tons.

Fifty million tons. The largest sea ship we have ever built is about 650,000 tons. Building something about 75 times the largest moving object we've ever made, in space for extra difficulty ... has certain near-term plausibility problems.

Interstellar travel actually requires superscience to make it economically viable. There are plenty of conventions for how you do this, but don't try to fool yourself this has real plausibility in the near future.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding John!

Comment: Oh, trust me. This is meant to be our first interstellar mission, so....... :P